# columns repated while combining multiple xml files using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the code available online to combine multiple xml files into single excel. It works fine but columns were repeated. Could someone help me in this, how to get rid of duplication while combining the xml files. Please find the code attached.

```
Sub From_XML_To_XL()
'UpdatebyKutoolsforExcel20151214
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xSWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xCount As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xSWb = ThisWorkbook
    xCount = 1
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Set xWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
        xWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy xSWb.Sheets(1).Cells(xCount, 1)
        xWb.Close False
        xCount = xSWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    xSWb.Save
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "no files xml", , "Kutools for Excel"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you ask us to do the work for you this is not the right place ([ask]). Please include in your question what you have tried to get rid of the duplicates. • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Please include a test data set that can be used to recreate the issue?